# Range php for chr(33, 47)

Tags: php

For capital letter I can use: `$capitalLetters = range(A,Z)`. It working also for a,z and 0,9. How can I do for the characters like: `/*-+.\`~!@#$%^&*()_+`

I was trying to do like that:

```
$other[] = chr(range(33, 47))
```

or

```
$other[] = range(chr(33, 47))
```

or

```
$other = range(chr(33, 47))
```

There is any solution (string or array) without to type every character: `/*-+.\~!@#$%^&*()_+?`

Comment: What's the reason for assembling an array anyway? What it's going to be used for? (This has all the marks of should just use a regex.)

Comment: I would like to check if a password contain some characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and any of: /*-+.!@#$%.....

Comment: So, basically a more tedious version of `preg_match("/[\x21-\x2F]/"` then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$other = array_map('chr',range(33,47));
```